# syntax error when attempting to dynamically write a search query

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to write a dynamic sql query. the query works ok with intergers. however once i tried to insert a string it fails.

below is my query:

```
public function getList($params['SearchBy'])
{ 

    $select = "
        SELECT  
           u.id, u.firstName,u.lastName,u.city";

$from = "
        FROM
        user u";

$where =  "  
        WHERE
            u.live = 1    ";

    if(isset($params['SearchBy']))
    {             
        $where .= 'AND '. implode(' AND ', $params['SearchBy']);
    }

    $GroupBy = " 
        GROUP BY 
             u.id ";

$sql = $select.$from.$where.$GroupBy;   

}
```

for the **searchby(),** i dynamically produce these values from a search query; i then place these in an array.:

```
$this->searchBy[$key][] = $key.' = '. $val;
```

this works perfectly when its an **integer**. however **strings** need to have "" . i am not sure to escape the ""so that it shows up in the query.
i.e

```
$this->searchBy[$topkey][] = $key.' = '. "$val";
```

i tried doing this but it did not work:

```
$this->searchBy[$topkey][] = $key.' = '. \"$val\";
```

would  appreciate any advice on how to escape it.

thank you.

below is the raw sql query-derived from the search ;

```
SELECT  
        u.id,u.picNo,
                u.membershipType,
                u.firstName,u.lastName
            FROM
            user u  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
                table_messages_between_members sm
        ON 
                u.id = sm.senderId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                list_photos_uploaded_by_members ph
        ON 
                u.id = ph.userId

            WHERE
                u.live = 1  AND u.membershipType = 1 AND u.city = London 
            GROUP BY 
                 u.id 
                ORDER BY
```

Comment: what does this contain $params['SearchBy'] ?

Comment: this question lacks the two most helpful things.  1) what your $sql string is before you execute it (ie, print it out), and 2) the full text of the error.  That said, right now, you have no space between `u.live = 1` and `AND`

Comment: hey pala. sorry in the actual query, there was space. also. its should be $params['Searchby']

Comment: can you please post `sql` it produce?

Comment: @PaulKendal then you should put the actual query, and the actual values in the array, and the actual error. Anything involves guesswork and just makes this whole process slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial solution would be

```
$this->searchBy[$topkey][] = $key.' = "'. $val .'"';
```

This approach, especially if available public by allowing end user to write/input values, can be a major security threat and **you should** [escape the input values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php) or use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) (even better).

Comment: @PaulKendal good to hear that, as i said, try using pdo. Might save you some bad moments. :)